# [AppGalleryConnectDynamicLinkManageService]the allowed-uris cannot be empty

Tags: deep-linking, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

Hell family, i want help in me deeplink generation with huawei app connect gallery

A error with app connect gallory on deeplink generation.

I make installation with this [documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agcapi-getstarted-0000001111845114#section103mcpsimp) but i have this error.

```
[AppGalleryConnectDynamicLinkManageService]the allowed-uris cannot be empty
```

Please, this error have block my work since 2 days actually

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls follow [this docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-allowlist-0000001059304615) to configure:

1. Sign in to AppGallery Connect and click **My projects**.
2. Click your project card.
3. Go to **Grow** > **App Linking** > **URL trustlist**, and click **New trusted URL format**.

[image]

4. Use a regular expression to add a trusted URL format and click **Release** in the upper right corner.

[image]

Comment: @F.Dakia, You're welcomeShould you need help with anything else, please feel free to reach out back to us.